# How to capture a cookie via a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script, manifest.json

I need to capture a cookie from an especific website and I am trying to do that using a Chrome extension, but I have never created one. I have read a lot of tutorials but I was not able to do that.

I am trying to capture the cookie using a content script, but I receive an error message every time.

This is the code of my manifest, content script and the error...

manifest.json

```
...
    
"manifest_version": 3,

"permissions": [
    "cookies"
 ],

"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["*://google.com/"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
}]
```

content.js

```
var ID;

function getCookies(domain, name) {
    chrome.cookies.get({"url": domain, "name": name}, function(cookie) {
        ID = cookie.value;
        showId();
    });
}

function showId() {
    alert(ID);
}

getCookies("https://google.com/", "SSID");
```

Error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

How can I fix it?

Comment: Content scripts can't use most of `chrome` API so do it in the background script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for `chrome.cookies.get`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/cookies/#type-CookieDetails) states:

> [...] If host permissions for this URL are not specified in the manifest file, the API call will fail.

You need to request permissions for all the domains for which you are interested in, which means adding them in the `permissions` declared in your `manifest.json`:

```json
"permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "*://google.com/"
],
```

Secondly, you don't actually need to inject a content script to extract the cookies. You can simply do this in your background page if you want.

Comment: I do not know a lot about Chrome extensions, this is my first one. How could I do that using a background script??

Comment: Do you know some book or some place where I can study more about it?

Comment: @KevenAugusto don't know about books, but [the welcome page of the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/) is a good place to start, it will teach you the basics and you will easily see how to write an extension that uses a background page.